# Is my logic correct? A bit string of n with more 0s than 1s

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs, bit-strings, string-theory

I am learning about combinatorial and bit strings.

I decided to use combinatorial reasoning and wanted to see if my logic made sense.

**The question: How many bit strings of length n contain more 0’s than 1’s?**

**Note: the length is unknown**

---

Let there be a bit string of length ( n )

with (k) as the number of 0s. We need to ensure

$ k > (n - k)$ as we want to show more 0s and 1s.

This can be simplify into $( 2k > n )$ or $\frac{n}{2} < k$

This can also be represented as a combination formula $\binom{n}{k}$ with the total number of bit strings being $\binom{n}{k}$ for all values of ( k ) satisfying k > $\frac{n}{2}$

We can represent it as

$\sum_{k = \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil}^{n} \binom{n}{k}$

where the sum of the binomial coefficients for choosing k positions out of  n  where k is greater than $\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: Of the $2^n$ strings with $n$ bits, some (how many?) have the same number of $1$s and $0$s.  By symmetry, half of the rest have more $0$s than $1$s.

Comment: @Henry Can you please tell me more on why half will have the same number of 1s and 0s instead of all?

We don't know how many strings. The goal is to just create an formula that can be used.

Comment: One way of looking at it is that if $k \le n$ then ${n\choose k} = {n\choose (n-k)}$ so that number of strings with more $0$s then $1$s is equal to the number of strings with more $1$s then $0$s.  Of course, that was just obvious common sense as whenever you have one string with so many $0$s and that many $1$s you can just replace ever $0$ with $1$ and ever $1$ with $0$ to get an exact "mirror opposite".

Comment: "Can you please tell me more on why half will have the same number of 1s and 0s instead of all" Henry never said any such thing.  He said there are $2^n$ strings total.  They are A) strings with equal numbers of $0$ and $1$s  B) strings with more $0$s than $1$s and C) strings with more $1$s than $0$.  He said B) and C) are have the same number, and A) has a specific number (which he left for you to figure out).  The unstated implication is $B = \frac {2^n- A}2$.  I'll give you the hint if $n$ is odd $A=0$.  And if $n = 2m$ then $A= {2m \choose m}$

Comment: It would have helped if you had actually stated what problem you are trying to solve?  Are you calculating how many strings have more $0$s than $1$. Calculating where a string (whether you know what it is isn't?) has more $0$s then $1$?  Are you trying to calculate if you know $k$ but not $n$ whether $k$ is more or less than $\frac 12 n$? You say "there are more 0s than 1s we need to showk>(n−k)"  We need to show that in order to do *what*?  ANd *how* can we show that if we don't know what either $k$ or $n$ is. Did yo actually mean "show" or did you mean "have"?  What *exactly* are you asking?

Comment: Hi @fleablood, I am asking what is the number of bits in a string that has more than 0s and 1s, not necessarily how many strings. I also clarified what I meant by show k > (n -k)

Comment: The reasoning in your post is correct. The other commenters are just trying to show you an approach that leads to a simpler answer (without the summation), based on the observation that exactly half of all strings have more 0s than 1s if you don't count strings that have an equal number of 0s and 1s.

Comment: If $n$ is odd then exactly half of the strings have more $0$s than $1$s (and the other half have more $1$s than $0$) so answer if $\frac {2^n}2= 2^{n-1}$.  If $n = 2m$ is even then there are ${2m\choose m}=$ strings with the same number of $1$s as $0$.  So there are $2^n - {n\choose \frac n2}$ strings with different numbers of $0$s and $1$.  Exactly half of those $\frac {2^n-{n\choose \frac n2}}2= 2^{n-1}- \frac {n!}{2\cdot (\frac n2!)^2}$ have more $0$s than $1$s. If, for example $n=4$ then $2^3-\frac{4\choose 2}2=8-3=5$ have more $0$s than $1$s. (and $5$ have more $1$s and $6$ have equal)